# Getting output and sending input to a minecraft server with the subprocess module

Tags: python, server, subprocess, minecraft

I'm trying to get minecraft server output and also be able to send input. I have this code:

```py
pipe = subprocess.Popen(f"java -Xms{RAM} -Xmx{RAM} -jar server.jar nogui", cwd=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "server"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, text=True)

while True:
    pipe.stdin.write(input("Enter a command: "))
    print("1")
    print(pipe.stdout.readline(), end="")
    pipe.stdout.flush()
    print("3")
```

And it seems to get the input of the server starting up each time, but then once it's fully loaded and I type a command, it freezes. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Why do you think you're going to get exactly 1 line of output for each line of input?

Comment: @Joseph I don't. I want to tie the latest line of output to a variable, and have that unrelated to the input stream, so they can work independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
with open("start.bat", "w+") as terminal:
    terminal.write("say Hello World!")
    output = terminal.readlines()
```